# Whats the best way to execute high processing tasks on low RAM VPS

Tags: linux, mysql, batch-processing

I have one VPS on internet and that have only 768MB of RAM.
Now i have run crawlers and various Optimzation algorithms /Data Mining Algos on the one mysql database.

I think i need better computer for those tasks but i can't buy VPS for that as it will be very costly.

I was thinking of buying the static IP and setup my local computer for processing tasks .

Cana anyone throw some light on some better solution

Comment: I think your VPS' internet connection is much better than yours at home, that's the bottleneck. Also I think that a server at home (24/7 - traffic - wattage) is more expensive than a VPS.  If the server location doesn't matter you should check out some VPS from Germany, they are much cheaper (with more power) than the international average.

Answer (score 0):

IF your needs fluctuate, such as you're doing the crawling only occasionally, but you need to read the data 24x7, you might want to look at using Amazon EC2 or equivalent services for doing the crawling.